# How to build serverless p2p chat application in React?

Tags: reactjs, webrtc, chat, p2p, stun

I would make a chat app where server communication is allowed only for signaling.

I checked this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmR9IMUD_CY

This video goes about "real time" communication, for me some delay is ok. I would make chat application which only send text, but not video content. The question raised for me:

1. How to generate ice candidates to get list ip addresses / ports? How to make request to stun server?
2. If we have the ip and port list shared through the signaling server on both side, then how one client call the other client and send or receive text? Can I use `axios` for sending, and set one of the ip - port pair from the list as url? How to receive message?

Maybe I do not even need `webrtc` as the data transmission does not need to be realtime, some delay is ok?

Would you show a basic demo?

Comment: React implies web, and the web isn't p2p, it's client-server. Any chat will relay messages though its server, as browser to browser communication is impossible.

Comment: What about web conference web apps? They can be built with React, isn't it? Though to keep them real time  they will not communicate through server. As the linked video demonstrate it also.

Comment: React is irrelevant here, the "problem" is the way the web and browsers are built. If you inspect the traffic you'll see that they ever only talk to the server, and its the server who resends the messages to each client. Browsers simply can't open connections to other browsers.

Comment: Please look at the video, there is the signalling part, and there is the data tranfer part. In the second iteration there is no server involved: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmR9IMUD_CY

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that is what you are looking for [Google Code Lab Friendly Chat](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web#0)
but if you want to learn more about WebRTc I really recommend  [this article](https://Build%20the%20backend%20services%20needed%20for%20a%20WebRTC%20app)  so you will can see if is that what you want.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).